# How can I encode a property of a value in its type in C?

Tags: c, types, struct, compile-time

In a plain C program, I have certain values of some type that may or may not have a certain property, and this property **must** hold for some users of this value. I wonder if/how we can use the type system to enforce this property at compile time for those called functions that need it.

For example, given this struct definition:

```
struct foo {
    bool has_property_bar;
    ...
}
```

Some functions take values of type `struct foo *` for which `has_property_bar` **must** be true, so they have to check this property by testing the relevant field at run time (typically with assert).

Now I wonder if it is possible to avoid these run time tests by defining a new type based on foo which would express that indeed the value has the required property. Maybe something like:

```
struct bar_compliant_foo {
    struct foo real_foo;
}

struct bar_compliant_foo *set_property_bar(struct foo *f) {
    f->has_property_bar = TRUE;
    return (struct bar_compliant_foo*)f;
}

int do_something_with_compliant_foo(struct bar_compliant_foo *bf) {
    struct foo *f = &bf->real_foo;
    ...
}
```

Does this work beyond toy programs? Are there other/better ways than using a struct that wrap the original type?

Comment: I guess you don't have any bits left. Upgrading your int to a larger size (int64) gives you bits to play with. OTOH, you might be better off with a struct because it will wreak havoc with all but the very simplest math operations.

Comment: What do you mean by locked? Do you want to create objects and inheritance?

Comment: "Does this work beyond toy programs?" This shouldn't work at all, at least not in most modern operating systems that have pre-emptive scheduling. "Are there other/better ways than using a struct that wrap the original type?" Yes, use locking mechanisms that actually interact with the scheduler. For C specifically, you should use mutexes (or semaphores) provided by the system. "I wonder if/how we can use the type system to check for this property." I'm not sure if we have the same interpretation of that term, but no, C's type system can't help you with concurrency problems.

Comment: This question is NOT about locking in any way. It is about being able to assert that a certain property holds for my object without resorting to run-time checks. Using the type system of the language is one way of ensuring at compile time that objects have certain properties, that's what I'm trying to do here in C.
I will remove references to "locking" because it seems to be misleading.

Comment: What's to stop someone calling `set_property_bar()`, changing the property back to `FALSE`, and then calling `do_something_with_compliant_foo()`? If `has_property_bar` is sometimes `TRUE`, and sometimes `FALSE`, obviously you cannot check this at compile time, because it's not decided until the program is run. If it needs to be true regardless of what the caller wants, then just make the first line of `do_something_with_compliant_foo()` be `f->has_property_bar = TRUE;` or similar, and you've guaranteed that it will be.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths nothing stops nobody from introducing bugs if they are careless (especially so in C), I just want to make it less likely to happen. Right now I do use assert() and read my code very very carefully... but it's painful. And in some cases I cannot coerce my struct into having the right property, it has to be good right away.

Comment: @jms: This is what `assert()` is for, there's no foolproof compile-time check, and trying to cobble together a halfway house of some kind will just make your code harder to read and more error-prone. Since `assert()` disappears in a release build, there's no meaningful penalty to using them.

Answer (score 0):

C is as bare and close to the silicon as a high level programming language can be. And the C type system reflects that idea: data types are just a bunch of bytes that you can alter at the same time. Ie, a double is an array of 8 bytes which you can alter at the same time to represent a floating point number. That's as far as the C type system goes.

If you want to enforce at compile time some certain program property, ie, a boolean variable to True, you must move to another programming language. You may try C++ with some voodoo magic template meta-programming. But by the type of question you are asking I guess you already have some background on strong statically typed programming languages.

Comment: In this case I don't have the option of switching a large existing code base to another language, so I try to make do with C.
BTW nowadays a C compiler complains when you mix pointers to different struct types, and that's already a certain level of strictness, so I wonder if smarter people managed to squeeze from the language the kind of feature I'm looking for here.